# Live Wallpaper touch and drag

Tags: android, touch, live-wallpaper, gesture-recognition, homescreen

How would you handle a touch and drag motion event on a live wallpaper to drag a bitmap in any direction?

SOLVED: Found a solution at http://www.andengine.org/forums/post22486.html#p22486